# Grandpa avoids cutting the grass

Tags: movies

Walking past Grandpa, who seemed to be snoozing, I saw a note in his left hand, with the name of a film I recognized on it. As I sat down opposite him, he opened his eyes.

Me: "What's on your mind Grandpa?"
Grandpa: "The lawn needs a trim, but I'd rather watch the film I've written down on this note in my hand."

Me: "Grandpa, if I can't guess the film, I'll cut the grass - front and back!"
Grandpa: "OK son, I'll give you some clues. It was released in a leap year, and won a prime number of Oscars."

I said the name of the film I'd seen on the piece of paper.

Grandpa smiled, handed it to me and said, "You've a lot to learn son, looks like I'll be watching my film after all."

What film had Grandpa written down, and how was I tricked?

<sup>In tribute to **DEEM**'s [Grandpa series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a34419%20%20Grandpa), which are so enjoyable and interesting.</sup>

Comment: I'm not an expert on films, but maybe rot13(bayl n cneg bs gur zbivr gvgyr jnf ivfvoyr va tenaqcn'f cvrpr bs cncre. Vg pbhyq or gur ivfvoyr cneg vf gur gvgyr bs nabgure zbivr juvpu nyfb jnf eryrnfrq va n yrnc lrne naq jba n cevzr ahzore bs Bfpnef)

Comment: I was going down the path of thinking that rot13(gur gvgyr vf n lrne gung ybbxf yvxr vg fcryyf fbzrguvat hcfvqr qbja, be ivpr irefn, ohg V pna'g svaq bar).

Comment: @Tom: doh, my brain hiccuped. I thought it said the release years were prime. But they're leap years.

Comment: Thanks for the attribution @Tom. This is the kind of thing Grandpa loves to do. Been there done that. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You guessed

> **Argo** (2012), which won three Oscars.

Grandpa's film was

> **Fargo** (1996), which won two Oscars.

How you were tricked:

> Grandpa was awake all along, and in order to trick you he deliberately concealed the first letter of the film with his thumb?

Credit to

> melfnt, who guessed the exact mechanism in the comments!

Comment: Ah yes, Frances's first Oscar-winning film!

Answer (score 2):

> It was the film TITANIC made in 1952, awarded 1 Oscar, that Grampa wanted to watch.
>  You read TITANIC and assumed he wanted to see the one made in 1996, awarded 11 Oscars.

Comment: It looks like [Titanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanic_(1953_film)) (maybe made in 1952) was released in 1953. The prime is in an older edition of Hardy's [Pure Mathematics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZD6b.png).

Comment: ^ [Edsger W. Dijkstra](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD12xx/EWD1203.html)

Comment: @Tom. Hardy expresses an opinion by definition of primes. 1 is a prime.

Comment: Technically 1 isn't a prime because 1 and itself are the same number.

Comment: @merrybot. Is  2 a prime yes or not.

Comment: **2** is a prime. **1** isn't.

Comment: @merrybot  According to Wikipedia the Goldbach conjecture states:  Every  even number greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes, so 2+3=5 but 5 is not an even number. In addition to that the sum of two odd numbers make an even number.  Also, if you add 1 to any odd number you always obtain an even number. (All numbers integers.)

Comment: A prime number is a number **greater than 1** that is not the product of any two numbers other than 1 and itself. I know my mathematics.

Comment: A prime is an integer with exactly two factors. 1 has a single factor, itself only, and is not prime. *"Every even number greater than 2 can be..."* means the conjecture applies only to even numbers greater than 2. 5 is not even, and neither 1 nor 2 are greater than 2, so none of Goldbach's conjecture is relevant here and doesn't prove anything to support you.

Comment: Not to mention the later film was not released in 1996...

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Not sure what your point is: the Goldbach conjecture *doesn't* state that every sum of 2 Primes is an even number.  A→B ≠ B→A .  Also, as 1 isn't a Prime Number, then the only way to obtain 4 is 2+2.  And, we specify "greater than 1", because otherwise 2 has 4 factors (1,2,-1,-2), and the only "prime" number would be -1 (with factors 1 and -1).  Perhaps a better description would be "An number whose only integer factor larger than 1 is itself"?

Comment: What a prime number "is" is a matter of *definition*, not some deep mathematical fact.  Historically, both 1 and 2 have been considered prime and not prime.  Defining the primes so that 1 is not a prime but 2 is can be convenient, but it is not universal, nor a provable fact.  Nearly every modern mathematician defines the primes so that 1 is not prime (because it makes many theorems easier to state), but there are a few iconoclasts.  In any event, the other answer is better, but I like the idea that Grandpa is tricky about his definition of primes (as well as using the same film title twice).